# Executing Arbitrary Code at a Specific URL without Creating a Post or Page?

Tags: hooks, url-rewriting

I am trying to figure out which hooks I can tie into in order to read the incoming URL prior to the query actually being run. A quick look tells me maybe `wp_loaded` or `posts_selection` would be good choices but would hate to miss out on something obviously better for my needs.

`template_redirect` sounded promising but seems to be called after content is selected so I do not think that is going to work.

I thought the rewrite code might help, but the likes of `generate_rewrite_rules` do not seem to allow for arbitrary code to be executed... it seems to all be geared toward redirecting to existing content.

My goal is to write redirection code that I need to not be tied to an existing piece of content. I have found several plugins that do similar things, but all seem to require that a post or page be added to the system for the redirect to be attached to.

For instance, I want `/foo/bar` to redirect to `/baz`, but I don't want to have to create a page `foo` or a sub-page of `foo` called `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

@Hi **Beau Simensen:**

The hook `plugsin_loaded` is one option, but you can use **the plugin** I posted for this question to see what plugins are run and in which order and use it to find the hook that works best for you:

- [**Where Can I Find a List of WordPress Hooks?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-wordpress-hooks/339#339)

Given your goal, you might also find this answer useful:

- [**Creating 301 Redirects for Post, Page, Category and Image URLs?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/creating-301-redirects-for-post-page-category-and-image-urls/1023#1023)

If that wasn't what you needed please elaborate and I can hopefully offer more.

Comment: The Creating 301 Redirects for Post, Page... uses `template_redirect` which seems to come after content has been queried. I verified this with your instrument-hooks plugin. This seems to me to be too late in the process as doing a query would wasted since I know no content will exist there. Love the instrument-hooks plugin, btw!

Comment: *@Beau Simensen:* That's why I suggested `plugsin_loaded` at the top of my answer. I was suggesting it with the code in the *"Creating 301..."* answer.