# Create page to handle form submission

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, forms

I currently have some custom post types "shops" (actually more like pages than posts) and a custom taxonomy "products" linked to those post types.

I'm attempting to create a form (via shortcode) that allows the user to select one (or potentially more in the future) products that when submitted, shows a page listing shops (title and other post meta) related to the chosen product(s).

I have the form, just not sure what the best way is to handle the submission and subsequent display page.

I noticed the codex page for [add_rewrite_endpoint()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API#add_rewrite_endpoint.28.29) states

> This can be used for all sorts of things:
>
> - ajax handler
> - **form submission handler**
> - alternative notification handler

however there's no further information about how to achieve this.

Any pointers on handling form submissions would be great. Thanks.

**Edit**: Further on this, I want the form submission page to redirect to a nice URL representing the selected term. For example

1. User selects product "books", hits submit
2. Form submits to handling URL **or** some kind of hook catches the submission
3. The browser is redirected to "shops/books"
4. Something displays the "shop" pages tagged with "books" products

My question can be broken down to...

1. What URL do I use in the form's `action` attribute? Is this even necessary?
2. Where do I handle the form submission? Do I create a specific file or can I register some kind of action hook. Keep in mind that I'm wanting to send a `Location` header to redirect to another URL so this needs to happen prior to any output sent to the browser.
3. How do I configure *something* to accept the "shops/%product%" request and show results accordingly

Sorry for the long-winded query but I'm struggling to get to grips with the Wordpress API and documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually really easy (at least #1 and #2 are):

1. You can use any URL that loads a theme template file. For example, you could create a WordPress *"[Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)"* and in your [**Page Template**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) you can use PHP's `$_POST` array to capture your `<form>`  values.
2. Unless you've got a good reason, you really don't need to do a redirect. You can, but I don't see that you need to and it just makes your task more complicated.  If you really want to [**this answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/creating-301-redirects-for-post-page-category-and-image-urls/1023#1023) will show you how.
3. I'm confused by what you are trying to accomplish with your "`shops/%product%`" URL. At first blush your choice of *"shops"* for a custom post type and *"products"* for a taxonomy seems wrong to me *(unless you are trying to represent many different shops; i.e. if your site is trying to be a marketplace for many different merchants. Is that the case?  Even then, I still don't see why you'd use a taxonomy for your products.)*  So it seems to me you'd instead want to create a custom post type of *"Product"* *(though I'm not sure about the taxonomy)*, and then you'll get URLs of the type `products/%product%` when you register you custom post type. Or maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to do for #3?

Comment: Thanks for the tips Mike. #2 - The listing pages will also need to be accessible via regular GET request so I'd like the form submission URLs to match. Also, I prefer the PRG pattern. #3 - Yes, there are multiple "shops". Also the "shops/" prefix is arbitrary. It could easily be "products" or "bananas" for all it matters ;-)

Comment: @Phil Brown - If you want accessibility via GET just used `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. As for the PRG pattern (which I had to google) the link in #2 shows you what you need for that. As for arbitrary URL names I must admit that I frequently find myself confused by things that don't confuse other merely based on the names that are used. I think my brain is wired such that I need to understand how the use-case properly applies to be able to understand the use-case, and for that well-chosen names are crucial. FWIW.